# The sum of three all three digit numbers, containing digits : 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: combinatorics

[image: This is the question]

First of all, there are $5^3 =125$ three-digit numbers (repetition of digits allowed).

We know that there are $555-111+1 = 445$ three-digit numbers between $555$ and $111$

This way, we can determine the sum of the numbers between $111$ and $555$ and then subtract the sum of the three-digit numbers that contain any of $6,7,8,9$.

My question is whether there's more efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there are $125$ possibilities. One fifth of these have $1$ in the hundreds place, one fifth have $2$ in the hundreds place etc. Similarly for the tens and units places. So we have $$\frac {125}5\times (1+2+3+4+5)\times 111 = 41,625$$

For the next problem, there are fewer possibilities $5\times 4 \times 3=60$ but the digits are still equally distributed - one fifth will have $1$ in each place etc. So the calculation becomes $$\frac {60}5\times (1+2+3+4+5)\times 111=19,980$$

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way:

Keep in mind that:
$$111+555=666$$ $$112+554=666$$$$113+552=666$$ $$114+551=666$$
$$...$$
So, until $111$ and $155$ there are $25$ combinations.
Then there are five such cases:
$$111-155$$$$211-255$$$$311-355$$$$411-455$$$$511-555$$

So, answer would be (dividing by two as we calculated the sum 2 times):

$$\frac{666*5*25}{2}=41625$$
Second part:
$$123+543=666$$
$$...$$
So, until $123$ and $154$ there are $12$ combinations. Then there are five such cases. So, answer would be:

$$\frac{666*5*12}{2}=19980$$

In a single sentence:

**You must multiply the number of combinations to the sum of the minimum and maximum and divide by $2$:**
$$\frac{125*(111+555)}{2}=41625$$

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a three digit number $\bar{abc}$ as $100a+10b+c$. Then, the required summation becomes:

$\sum_{\{a,b,c\}\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}} \bar{abc} = \sum_{a}\sum_{b}\sum_{c} 100a+10b+c$

Now, since the rightmost summation is only over $c$, so $a$ and $b$ can be seen as constants. So, basically the rightmost (innermost) summation for $c\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ can be written as: $(100a+10b+1) + (100a+10b+2) + ... + (100a+10b+5) = 5*100a + 5*10b + 15$.

Now, the overall summation becomes as follows:

$\sum_{a}\sum_{b}\sum_{c} 100a+10b+c = \sum_{a}\sum_b (500a+50b+15)$

Similarly, we can do the same thing for the summation on $b$, and assume $a$ is constant, and get:

$\sum_{a}\sum_{b}\sum_{c} 100a+10b+c = \sum_{a} (2500a+750+75)$

Finally, there is one more summation to get the overall sum, which I'll leave it to you.

Comment: This is a completely different approach. Thanks!